# Did a Wisconsin school file sexual harassment complaints over pronoun usage?

Tags: united-states, law, children, school, lgbt

The [New York Post](https://nypost.com/2022/05/14/kiel-wisconsin-school-charges-kids-for-using-wrong-pronouns/) claims

> A Wisconsin school district has filed sexual harassment complaints against three middle schoolers for calling a classmate by a wrong pronoun.

They cite [fox17.com](https://fox17.com/news/nation-world/sexual-harassment-investigation-launched-into-3-middle-schoolers-wrong-use-of-pronouns-lgbtq-discrimination-allegations-kiel-wisconsin-title-xi-9-trans-transgender-pronouns-he-him-she-her-they-theirs) as source, which returns error-message **403 Forbidden**. A rudimentary search finds similar headlines, but few sources with reputation.

Have there been filings of sexual harassment against three middle schoolers? If so, are these because of misusage of pronouns?

Comment: The Fox source works for me and appears to have at least one reputable enough source backing it. Can you check out [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20220513193102/https://fox17.com/news/nation-world/sexual-harassment-investigation-launched-into-3-middle-schoolers-wrong-use-of-pronouns-lgbtq-discrimination-allegations-kiel-wisconsin-title-xi-9-trans-transgender-pronouns-he-him-she-her-they-theirs)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This appears to be accurate according to local news sources. [Parents want Kiel boys cleared of sexual harassment accusations](https://www.wbay.com/2022/05/12/parents-want-kiel-boys-cleared-sexual-harassment-accusations/):

> KIEL, Wis. (WBAY/Gray News) - The parents of three Wisconsin middle
> school students are asking the school district to stop a sexual
> harassment investigation into their sons and clear their records of
> any sort of charges or investigation.
>
> The parents say that according to the Kiel Area School District, the
> Kiel Middle School students are under investigation for mispronouncing
> pronouns when referring to a classmate.
>
> Last month, the parents of the three eighth-graders were notified
> their sons were being charged by school district officials with sexual
> harassment. A section of Title IX prohibits gender-based harassment in
> the form of name-calling on the basis of sex.
>
> The district claims the boys were not referring to the student’s
> requested pronouns of “they” and “them.”
>
> Rose Rabidoux, the mother of a student involved, told WBAY she
> accompanied her son the day after the notification to an interview
> with school officials. She told them the use of the pronouns was
> confusing to her son, and he had no obligation to refer to the
> classmate by those pronouns.
>
> “Sexual harassment, that’s rape, that’s incest, that’s inappropriate
> touching,” Rabidoux said. “What did my son do? He’s a little boy. He
> told me that he was being charged with sexual harassment for not using the right pronouns.”

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136348/discussion-on-answer-by-joe-w-did-a-wisconsin-school-file-sexual-harassment-comp).